# MySQL group by first week value while including second week value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to achieve the following:

I have a table with data like this:

```
    INSERT INTO `control_leads` (`LeadID`, `Type`, `Business`, `Date`, `Multiplier`, `UserID`)
VALUES
    (1026, 'Bags', 'AB', '2017-01-18', 1, 11),
    (1030, 'Ice Scraper', 'AB', '2017-01-18', 1, 8),
    (1029, 'Drawstring ', 'AB', '2017-01-18', 1, 8),
    (1028, 'Umbrellas', 'AB', '2017-01-18', 1, 11),
    (1027, 'Lanyards', 'LP', '2017-01-18', 2, 11),
    (1025, 'Bags', 'AB', '2017-01-18', 2, 8),
    (1031, 'Lanyards', 'LP', '2017-01-18', 2, 8),
    (1018, 'Lanyards', 'LP', '2017-01-17', 1, 8),
    (1017, 'Bags', 'AB', '2017-01-17', 1, 8),
    (1023, 'Hand Warmer', 'AB', '2017-01-17', 1, 8),
    (1020, 'Lanyards', 'LP', '2017-01-17', 2, 11),
    (1021, 'Pens', 'AB', '2017-01-17', 1, 11),
    (1022, 'Bags', 'AB', '2017-01-17', 1, 8),
    (1024, 'Headphones', 'AB', '2017-01-17', 1, 11),
    (1007, 'Balls', 'AB', '2017-01-16', 1, 8),
    (1008, 'Lanyards', 'LP', '2017-01-16', 2, 8),
    (1009, 'Mugs', 'AB', '2017-01-16', 1, 11),
    (1010, 'Bags', 'AB', '2017-01-16', 1, 8),
    (1011, 'Bags', 'AB', '2017-01-16', 1, 11),
    (1013, 'Phone/Table', 'AB', '2017-01-16', 1, 8),
    (1015, 'Pens', 'AB', '2017-01-16', 1, 11),
    (1016, 'Selfie Stic', 'AB', '2017-01-16', 1, 8);
```

Here is my sql query:

```
SELECT IFNULL( SUM(Multiplier), 0) AS val, control_leads.Date AS date
FROM control_leads
WHERE Date > '2017-01-04'
GROUP BY control_leads.Date
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Results in:

```
10  2017-01-05
6   2017-01-06
8   2017-01-09
14  2017-01-10
9   2017-01-11
14  2017-01-12
10  2017-01-13
10  2017-01-16
8   2017-01-17
10  2017-01-18
```

But I am trying to get this weeks values but also includes the last week comparison

Like this:

```
val1  week1        val2  week2
10    2017-01-05   14    2017-01-12
6     2017-01-06   10    2017-01-1
8     2017-01-09   10    2017-01-16
14    2017-01-10   8     2017-01-17
9     2017-01-11   10    2017-01-18
```

EDIT:

I did not explain very well, I want to group by day and compare it with the value of lastweek on that day.

```
      val1  week1        val2  week2
   day1 10    2017-01-05   14    2017-01-12
   day2 6     2017-01-06   10    2017-01-1
   day3 8     2017-01-09   10    2017-01-16
   day4 14    2017-01-10   8     2017-01-17
   day5 9     2017-01-11   10    2017-01-18
```

Comment: Nearly. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Not a single one of the data rows you inserted is in 2017, how are you getting the results you describe with `WHERE Date > '2017-01-04'`?

Comment: @CharlesBretana it's was used as an example. The actual table is massive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for comparing to last week, by day

```
SELECT
cl.date
, sum(cl.multiplier) val
, cl2.date last_week
,  ifnull(cl2.last_week_val,0) last_week_val
, sum(cl.multiplier) - ifnull(cl2.last_week_val,0) diff 
FROM control_leads cl 
  LEFT JOIN (select t.date, sum(t.multiplier) last_week_val from control_leads t group by t.date) cl2 
  ON (cl2.date = cl.date-7)
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

[Here is a functional example](http://rextester.com/LDKG84962)

Comment: Sorry i think i did not explain it very well, I am trying to group by day.

Comment: @jrobilliard that is much easier and cleaner!

Comment: @jrobilliard i updated my answer.  You can click the link as well to see how it works with a dataset